# Rsync on a browser does not work

Tags: php, rsync

I am trying to transfer files from one server to another with the code below.

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /root/.ssh/somekey" /var/www/admin/somefiles.txt root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/var/www/html_public/some-folder/
```

It works just fine if I do this on putty but if I do `shell_exec` this code on a php page and run the page on a browser. It does not work. It returns an empty string.

I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to check if you need to be a root or (sudo user) for running rsync.

If yes then exec() command will only work if it is run by same user on `php-cli` (not on browser by Apache user). i.e. Which user you are loggined into shell for run `rsync`.

If it is root or any elavated permission user with sudo permission then, This `rsync` command may not be available to `apache/www-data` user which is working when php script run from browser.

So You try to make a normal user and login through it, Then try `rsync` if you are successful then it may be interesting to see what are other problems can be, But if you getting access/permission denied then obviously you can not run this script at-least on browser.

Besides this One more thing permission may not be directly related to `rsync`  command itself but with folder `/etc/test/` which is owned by root user in normal scenario.